# A functor preserving adjunction between functor categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

I have the following problem. Let $\mathcal{C}_0$, $\mathcal{C}$ be small categories and $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{E}$ be locally small categories. Let $Q\colon \mathcal{C}_0\to \mathcal{C}$ be a functor and let
$$
Q_!\colon [\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{D}]\rightleftarrows  [\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{D}]\colon Q^\ast
$$
be a corresponding adjunction between functor categories, where the right adjoint is the pullback and the left adjoint is the left Kan extension along $Q$. Similarly, we have the adjunction
$$
Q_!\colon [\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{E}]\rightleftarrows  [\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{E}]\colon Q^\ast.
$$

Further on, let $F\colon \mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{E}$ be a functor. Now the question is: if I know that the following diagram is commutative (note the direction of arrows), where $F_\ast$ denotes composition with $F$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
[\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{D}] @<{Q^\ast}<<[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]\\
@V F_\ast V V @VV F_\ast V\\
[\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{E}] @<{Q^\ast}<< [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{E}]
\end{CD}

under what conditions I can derive that the following diagram is also commutative?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
[\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{D}] @>Q_!>> [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]\\
@V F_\ast V V @VV F_\ast V\\
[\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{E}] @>>Q_!> [\mathcal{C},\mathcal{E}]
\end{CD}

---

A remark: specific example which I have in mind is that $D$ is the category of topological spaces, $E$ is the category of chain complexes of abelian groups and $F$ is the functor of singular chains. If the above question is too general, I would be happy with an idea/reference how to prove only this case.

---

This question is a follow-up to this one: [Reduction to graph subgroups for Bredon homology when the $G_1\times G_2$ is $G_2$-free](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395183/reduction-to-graph-subgroups-for-bredon-homology-when-the-g-1-times-g-2-is-g).

Comment: There is always a canonical natural transformation; the condition that it be invertible  is known as a [Beck-Chevalley condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Beck-Chevalley+condition). There are a number of generic situations where it holds. Another relevant keyword is [exact square](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/exact+square) (although on second thought the latter may not be so relevant to your situation).